# OpenGL 16 bit stencil buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create framebuffer with 4 colour attachments, a 16 bit depth buffer and a 16 bit stencil buffer. I need 16 bits for the stencil buffer because I store object ID's in them for object picking, and I have a lot more then 255 objects. I create two render buffers:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, mID);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, mID2);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX16, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
```

I ask SDL to give me 16 bit stencils:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 16);
```

But when I bind the stencil render buffer to the framebuffer I get a framebuffer incomplete error. I know the wiki states that GL_STENCIL_INDEX16 is not required by the spec. Is it not possible to create 16 stencil buffers? Could I encode the object ID integers down to 8 bit values?

Comment: "*I need 16 bits for the stencil buffer because I store object ID's in them for object picking*" Why would you use a stencil buffer for that? You can just use a 16-bit, single-channel, unsigned integer image format. Unless you're doing actual stencil operations, you shouldn't be using a stencil buffer.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're right, that was a much simpler fix than I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A separate depth and stencil buffer attachment need not be supported.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 9.4.3 Required Framebuffer Formats](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=354&zoom=100,168,173)

> [...] However, when both depth and stencil
> attachments are present, implementations are only required to support framebuffer
> objects where both attachments refer to the same image.

See also:

[Unable to attach separate stencil buffer to FBO (packed depth+stencil is fine)](https://community.khronos.org/t/unable-to-attach-separate-stencil-buffer-to-fbo-packed-depth-stencil-is-fine/70708)

[Framebuffer Object - Completeness Rules](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules)

Comment: So that means I'm limited to packed formats like GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8?

Comment: @NicovanBentum It seems that there are just 2 combined depth/stencil formats which are supported. See [Depth stencil formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_stencil_formats): *"[...] There are only 2 depth/stencil formats, each providing 8 stencil bits: `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` and `GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8`"*